# Discord.js - @user avatar command not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const discord = require('discord.js'); // Import the discord.js module
var client = new discord.Client(); // Create an instance of a Discord client
```

I've declared `discord` at the top but continue to get a referencing error, am I missing something extremely obvious?

```
// Send the user's avatar URL
if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "avatar")) {
   const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
   const avatarEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Discord is not defined`,

Discord (with a capital D) is not declared anywhere in the program,

`const discord = require('discord.js'); // Import the discord.js module`

here you declare "discord" as the discord.js module, so you should be using "discord" instead of "Discord".

Comment: Ever since changing that, the error has stopped but now the command '''!h avatar @user''' does nothing, any advice?

Comment: Couldn't tell you - i can't see where `config` is defined to see what config.prefix is, looks like there's no space between config.prefix and "avatar" though, maybe you need to insert a leading spaces such that it's `" avatar", as you might be asking for the command !havatar, or something - no idea.

Comment: prefix is "!h " all my other commands work just fine

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html, these docs may help.